# How to kill a python thread by name or by id?

Tags: python, multithreading

Can I kill a thread by name or by id ?

I´m doing some tests with this code:

in 1, it will start a thread to populate a file.
in 2, it would kill (the thread), stopping the specific file fill.

How I would proceed ?

```
import threading 
import time
import os

def do_job(stop_id): 
    t = threading.current_thread().native_id
    print("native id " + str(t))
    print("irei criar o arquivo : " + str(t))    

    while True:          
        f = open("C://temp//py//" + "arquivo_" + str(t) + ".txt", "a")
        time.sleep(1)
        f.write("RESULTADO DO ID=" + str(t) + "\n")

i=0
threads=[]
while True:
    print ("1 para startar")
    print ("2 para parar")  
    result = int ( input("Opcao: "))    
    if result == 1:
        print("criando arquivo com select!")
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=do_job, args = [0]))   
        threads[i].start()
        i = i + 1
    if result == 2:    
        print("qual thread q eh para acabar?")
        acabar = int ( input("id=") )
        print("acabei com a thread q estava na posicao " + str(acabar))
```

I tried to use multiprocessing.process instead, but it waits for the process ends, not backing to the menu instead.

I know that is not a good idea to kill threads like this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your threads, you can check for an [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) object. So you may have a dictionary of thread ids to their event objects and when user presses 2, you `.set()` that Event object.

Also I've let threads to be daemon so that they terminate when the main thread finishes(by exception maybe) and it doesn't hang until you kill the main thread. It may not be what you want so set that accordingly.

```py
import time
import threading
from threading import Event


def do_job(stopping_event: Event):
    thread_id = threading.current_thread().native_id
    print("native id " + str(thread_id))
    print("irei criar o arquivo : " + str(thread_id))

    while not stopping_event.is_set():
        f = open("C://temp//py//" + "arquivo_" + str(t) + ".txt", "a")
        time.sleep(1)
        f.write("RESULTADO DO ID=" + str(thread_id) + "\n")
    print(f"thread with id: {thread_id} stopped.")


threadId_events_map: dict[int, Event] = {}

while True:
    print("1 para startar")
    print("2 para parar")
    result = int(input("Opcao: "))
    if result == 1:
        print("criando arquivo com select!")
        event = Event()
        t = threading.Thread(target=do_job, args=[event], daemon=True)
        t.start()
        threadId_events_map[t.native_id] = event
    elif result == 2:
        print("qual thread q eh para acabar?")
        acabar = int(input("id="))
        threadId_events_map[acabar].set()
```

Comment: Its the answer!